How to delete the print statement itself after a few seconds in Python?
I am trying to make a text-based adventure game and I want to be able to have text self-delete itself.
For example, the game will use the print() statement to print the text, which will then be deleted or hidden from the player after 5 seconds.
I've tried to find other people's questions about this problem and can't find any info. I don't know what commands to use or anything related to that, please help.

If the cursor hasn't advanced to the next line, you can print a bunch of backspaces to back up to the beginning of the current line and then print a bunch of spaces to overwrite the existing text.

This question is similar to: How to clear only last one line in python output console?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Just for future discussions. you don't want to "delete the print statement itself" like your question says.  The print statement is part of your code.  What you want is to erase text that's on the screen.

Do you want to clear the whole terminal after the specified time?
import os  
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')


See original source here

If you want to clear just one line:
print("your game text here", end = '\r')


use the \r as the end character while displaying the text (which is supposed to be deleted after 5 seconds),
then print blank spaces (print(" "*length)) where length is the supposed max length of your game text


See original source here

Hope you find this useful!

For the second method, one can also simply print the next message if it is at least as long as the previous one (and if it isn't long enough, you can pad it with spaces using ljust).

@AlexDuchnowski the op mentioned he/she wanted to make the text deleted or hidden, that's why I suggested to print blank spaces. You can print the next text message as well though.

Let's do this by changing the Cursor position in the Windows console
befor you startd read about ctypes if you are not familiar with that
each character in console have position of X & Y so lets make class named COORD for this like way documents says
import ctypes

class COORD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("X", ctypes.c_short), ("Y", ctypes.c_short)]

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.X = x
        self.Y = y

now lets make class named TextField for your text with behavior you want
(show & hide)
import ctypes
from time import sleep



class TextField():
    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11
    hOut = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    text = ""
    def __init__(self,x,y,maxlegnth):
        self.pos = COORD(x,y)
        self.maxlegnth = maxlegnth
    
    def setText(self,text):
        if len(text) > self.maxlegnth:
            raise OverflowError(f"yout text legnth is {len(text)} but max legnth for this text field is {self.maxlegnth}")
        self.text = text
        

    def show(self,timelive=None):
        # if timelive not be set text never will be deleted
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition(self.hOut, self.pos)
        print(self.text)
        if timelive:
            sleep(timelive)
            del self
    
    
      
    def clearText(self):
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition(self.hOut, self.pos)
        print(" "*self.maxlegnth)
        
    def __del__(self):
        self.clearText()
        
    

so when you use del on obejct in python the __del__ method will be called
I could hide text like this
def show(self,timelive=None):
            ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition(self.hOut, self.pos)
            print(self.text)
            if timelive:
                sleep(timelive)
                self.clearText()

and this is work fine but i did use del and __del__ on purpose to be more flexible if you need to use it somewhere outside the class and make you familiar with that
so this the code will be something like this
import ctypes
from os import system
from time import sleep


class COORD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("X", ctypes.c_short), ("Y", ctypes.c_short)]

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.X = x
        self.Y = y

class TextField():
    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11
    hOut = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    text = ""
    def __init__(self,x,y,maxlegnth):
        self.pos = COORD(x,y)
        self.maxlegnth = maxlegnth
    
    def setText(self,text):
        if len(text) > self.maxlegnth:
            raise OverflowError(f"yout text legnth is {len(text)} but max legnth for this text field is {self.maxlegnth}")
        self.text = text
        

    def show(self,timelive=None):
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition(self.hOut, self.pos)
        print(self.text)
        if timelive:
            # sleep takes a float number if you need half second use 0.5 etc.
            sleep(timelive)
            del self
    
    
      
    def clearText(self):
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition(self.hOut, self.pos)
        print(" "*self.maxlegnth)
        
    def __del__(self):
        self.clearText()
        
    

def main():
    # use this to celar screen
    system("cls")
    # text position x,y zero is top left corner
    textfield = TextField(x=0,y=0,maxlegnth=10)
    textfield.setText("test1")
    # creating a time delay of 2 seconds
    textfield.show(2)
    textfield.setText("test2")
    textfield.show(2)


main()


this is just dummy example. It might give you the right insight
in solving the problem


the Cursor Position start at top left corner so its x=0 and y=0
But in some operating systems it is different, which is rare

ctypes.WinDLL

    import time
import sys

def print_and_replace(text, replacement_text, delay=5):
    print(text, end='', flush=True)  
    time.sleep(delay)  
    

    sys.stdout.write('\r' + ' ' * len(text)) 
    sys.stdout.write('\r')  
    sys.stdout.write(replacement_text)  
    sys.stdout.flush()

print_and_replace("This will be replaced in 5 seconds...", "This is the new text!", 5)


instead of deleting the text it instead just outputs the after text directly on top

retry it i have edit the code

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
